# Remover parte sem tamanho fixo de um xml

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Galera,
Tenho esse pedaço de um XML e necessito retirar o valor (357122.40) que está entre as tags < vMerc>xxxxxx< /vMerc>. Só que esse valor não tem tamanho fixo.

```
...<infCTeNorm><infCarga><vMerc>357122.40</vMerc><proPred>...
```

Tentei fazendo esse SQL:

```
SUBSTRING((CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), xml_conhecimento)), (PATINDEX('%<infCTeNorm><infCarga><vMerc>%', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), xml_conhecimento)) + 30), (((PATINDEX('%</vMerc><proPred>%', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), xml_conhecimento))) - (PATINDEX('%<infCTeNorm><infCarga><vMerc>%', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), xml_conhecimento))))-30))
```

Mas não funciona em tabela com muitos registros. Aparecendo o seguinte erro:

Mensagem 537, Nível 16, Estado 3, Linha 56
Parâmetro de comprimento inválido passado para a função LEFT ou SUBSTRING.

Comment: 2 perguntas: Você poderia disponibilizar o XML inteiro? Saberia nos dizer em qual XML o seu SQL falha?

Comment: Segue link de um xml e não sei onde falha: 
https://www.webdanfe.com.br/danfe/exemplos/CTe_assinado.html

Answer (score 1):

Esse erro significa que a função `SUBSTRING` está a receber um valor negativo no parametro `start` ou no parametro `length`.

Se o valor pretendido aparece aparece sempre entre as tags `<vMerc></vMerc>` , está aqui uma solução que funciona sempre. Retorna `NULL` caso não encontre nenhum valor.

Usei variáveis apenas para que fosse mais fácil ler e testar o código, substituir de acordo.

```
declare @xml        nvarchar(max)
declare @tagAbrir   nvarchar(200)
declare @tagFechar  nvarchar(200)
declare @pattern    nvarchar(max)
declare @inicio     int
declare @fim        int
declare @compriNum  int

set @xml        = '<infCTeNorm><infCarga><vMerc>357122.40</vMerc><proPred>'
set @tagAbrir   = '<vMerc>'
set @tagFechar  = '</vMerc>'
set @pattern    = '%'+ @tagAbrir + '%' + @tagFechar + '%'


set @inicio     = CASE WHEN PATINDEX(@pattern, @xml)>0 
                  THEN PATINDEX(@pattern, @xml) + LEN(@tagAbrir) 
                  ELSE NULL END
set @fim        = CHARINDEX(@tagFechar,@xml,@inicio)
set @compriNum  = @fim + LEN(@tagFechar) - @inicio - LEN(@tagAbrir)

select SUBSTRING(@xml,@inicio,@compriNum-1) AS Valor
```